# Separate processes that communicate via a NSpipe

Tags: nstask, nspipe

I need to realize a communication between two application using NSPipe channels.A NSPipe has to write data and the other has to read the data (Bi-directional) that will communicate between separate process in two different applications.

For example such things in c# can be easy done with NamedPipeClientStream, NamedPipeServerStream classes where pipes are registered by id string.

Any suggestion how to achieve it in Objective-C?

With regards,
Vadivelu